# SSMS How to set alternate row colors in Grid Results - Same as Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: ssms

How can I set alternating row colors in SSMS?

The ONLY answer close to what I'm looking for is here however is not for SSMS: [Make Oracle SQL Developer act like PL/SQL Developer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93728/make-oracle-sql-developer-act-like-pl-sql-developer)

However, the answer is the opposite of mine where I am using SSMS attempting to get the SSMS grid to appear similar to Oracle SQL Developer.

When attempting to search for this feature there are only results for how to accomplish this in SSRS.  Working in Oracle for 8 years and now working with SSMS for 4 years I'm just not impressed with SSMS yet and I keep making attempts to make it similar to Oracle SQL Developer.

Oracle SQL Developer Grid Results Color Scheme:

[image: Oracle SQL Developer Grid Results Color Scheme]

The closest I've come to SSMS is setting ONE color in the grid results as seen in the below screenshot.  Using same brown color as Oracle SQL Developer.  Using the Yellow by itself does not work well especially with the SSMS NULL fields being close the that same yellow.

[image: SSMS Updated Background Color]